# Translator with read from text file line by line and compare with getText from editText

Tags: android, file-io, android-edittext

I am very interested on App Development. But i began only two months ago so I have no experience.... I try to make a little translator app for my self. I have an EditText for Input and TextView for Output. the Idea is to read from EditText, search in a Text Document line by line with Line Number like
for Example:

1. Apple - Apfel
2. Car - Auto

then find the word and bring the translated word to textView
for Example:

EditText word is: Apple
the word is found Textview is: Apfel

If the word not founded so make TextView error message.

I have an Idea for make an Alert Dialog for Empty EditText
"eingabe" is my text value from EditText 
So what i want to do was, that the Method look at EditText and get the text from there. When the Field is empty it comes an error message in form of an AlertDialog. If the field is not empty the Method take the Value and compares it with my Dictionary wich is saved in my Assets folder. thats why o need a InputStream and a Reader! But i have no idea how i write the correct syntax for the Code.

This is my Complete Method
eingabe means EditText

```
public void sucheErgebnis() throws IOException{


    final Context context = DeutschActivity.this;
    final String str;
    final String eingabe = txtEingabe.getText().toString();
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    InputStream is = this.getResources().getAssets().open("dictionary.rtf");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    btnSuch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSuch);
    btnSuch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(Objects.equals(eingabe, "")){

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Dikkat")
                        .setMessage("Arama alani bos kalamaz!")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                txtEingabe.setSelection(0);

                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();

            }
            else{



            }



        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written this code which will read through the file (as format mentioned by you) stored in asset folder and return the translated word:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText txtEingabe;
Button  btnSuch;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtEingabe = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtEingabe);
    btnSuch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSuch);
    try {
        sucheErgebnis();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public void sucheErgebnis() throws IOException {


    final Context context = MainActivity.this;
    final String str;
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    btnSuch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String eingabe = txtEingabe.getText().toString().trim();
            if(eingabe.equals("")){

                new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                        .setTitle("Dikkat")
                        .setMessage("Arama alani bos kalamaz!")
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                txtEingabe.setSelection(0);

                            }
                        })
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();

            }
            else{
                String translatedWord = FileReaderFromAssets.read(context, eingabe);
                if(!translatedWord.equals("")){
                   txtEingabe.setText(translatedWord);
                 }
                 else{
                    // write your code here if that word not present in the rtf file
                 }

            }



            }

    });

}
```

Here is the method which search through the file and return the matched word, "" if match not found:

```
public class FileReaderFromAssets {

    public static String read(Context context, String word){
       String translatedWord = "";
       BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            String[] line;
            reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("dictionary.rtf"))); 

        // do reading, usually loop until end of file reading
        String mLine;
        while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = mLine.split("-");
            String temp= line[0].trim();
            if(temp.equalsIgnoreCase(word.trim())){
                translatedWord = line[1].trim();
                break;
            }
        }
        return translatedWord;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return translatedWord;
    }

    finally{

        try{

            reader.close();

        }catch(IOException ex){

        }

    }

  }
}
```

Comment: first of all Thank you very much. The Code runs very well, but i dont understand where to put the error feedback when the word not exists in dictionary.rtf

Comment: is it right that the "if" comes inside the last try-catch after the reader is close?

Comment: @bunkar I have updated the code. Try it out hope resolve this issue also.

Comment: Thank you one more time..you have saved my night. now i can implement my List. I only codet in else statement

Comment: txtErgebnis.setText("Word Not Found");

Comment: If one's answer helped you. Then why not to accept and vote up.